# Can the group of bijections on an infinite set be finitely generated?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be an infinite set and $B(S)$ the collection of all bijections $S\to S$.

I know that $B(S)$ is a group (when endowed with composition of maps).

My question is: can $B(S)$ be generated by finitely many elements?

Comment: Hint: $B(X)$ is not countable.

Comment: While $B (S) $ is not finitely generated, it has some interesting properties in common with finite groups: every generating set for the group produces a bounded Cayley graph. This is proved in "Generating infinite symmetric groups" by Bergman.

Answer (score 3):

If $\aleph$ is the (infinite) cardinality of the set $S$, the cardinalty of the set of bijections from $S$ to $S$ is at most $\aleph^{\aleph}=2^{\aleph}$. But this is also a lower bound: split $S$ in $\aleph$ many pairs (Axiom of Choice needed). For every pair one can either swap it or not, yielding at least $2^{\aleph}$ many bijections. So the cardinality of $B(S)$ equals $2^{\aleph}$. Obviously an uncountable group cannot be generated by a finite set of elements (which implies at most a countable order of the group).

Comment: You can prove without the axiom of choice that every finitely generated group is countable, but no infinite set exists whose group of self bijections is countable.

Comment: @Asaf, thanks (toda) for the interesting remark! +1 from me.